# Can't re-install after Panic

Tags: system-installation

I have an Asus Eee PC r101 that runs Ubuntu 12.04.
After running the Janitor that comes with Tweak, my drivers were gone.
L ong story short, all my attempts to recover the system failed so I went for a complete re-installation (of 14.04) using a live USB thumb.

Installation worked fine, up to a point, then it stopped and took me to a terminal where it informed me about Panic. I suppose I touched the USB thumb and it disconnected for a moment (my hardware is pretty old), can't be sure though.

Now when I try to re-install, the installer gets stuck in a black screen after the splash screen (the one with the 4 dots).

Running with nomodeset, acpi= off and quiet splash disabled gives some information. Since I'm not exactly sure what to look for and the output comes pretty fast, I'll just focus on what struck my eyes first in this post:

```
/sda1/ volume was not properly unmounted, please run fschk
cp: no free space 
failed to create /tmp/.X11-unix
```

this is probably not 100 percent accurate And as I am doing it from memory, but I guess that's the gist of it. The whole thing then gets stuck after the following lines:

```
sd 0:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
random: like urandom read with 73 bits of entropy available
bio: create slab <bio-1> at 1
random: non blocking pool is initialized
```

The system  has been at this point all night. Same thing happens when I `try ubuntu without installing`.

Does anyone have a solution or suggestion?